# Datatables, match portion of text

Tags: search, filter, datatables

I followed the example on DataTables website, but I can't get my filtering field to find what I want.

Let's say I have these strings:

1. This is a text
2. This is another text
3. Text here

Both global and column search, when searching for "text" (case-insensitive), return string 3 only. Why?
This is my code for the search function, almost the same as the [examples](https://datatables.net/reference/api/search%28%29):

```
$('#datatable').DataTable()
    .columns( colX )
    .search( $(this).val(), false, true )
    .draw();
```

I did not implement the search function for global search, so I think it is using the built-in one, I just made the column search.

Comment: This sounds weird - it is not possible to reproduce the error -> http://jsfiddle.net/tcy0pfj5/

Comment: I noticed that if I search for "%text" I get the correct output, so this made me think that I should edit my php page that receive searched keys and returns matched rows... I thought that DataTables plugin would have run the search in the cached rows, but I was wrong